# How can I inherit the preferred size of a ComboBox or ChoiceBox in Java FX from the current selection?

Tags: java, javafx-2, preferredsize

It appears that `ComboBox` and `ChoiceBox` just have an arbitrarily set preferred width. I don't want to have to guess an appropriate width; I'd like to just inherit the preferred width based on the items in the selection.

Another thing I noticed is that for both `ComboBox` and `ChoiceBox`, the popup when I click to select has a proper width based on the options in the selection. But the chooser itself doesn't inherit this width!

Answer (score 0):

With `ComboBox`, doing a `setPrefWidth(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);` followed by a `setNeedsLayout(true);` did it. For some strange reason, if I do this with `ChoiceBox` instead of `ComboBox`, when the component comes up it's sized wrong, but after I've changed the selection a couple times it eventually resizes to just fit the content.